# Docker selenium 2.53 cannot override maxInstances and maxSession with env variables

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

so I have the following docker compose config:

```
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:2.53.1
    environment:
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=30000

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:2.53.1
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm # Mitigates the Chromium issue described at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=519952
    environment:
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=4
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=4

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug:2.53.1
    environment:
      - FIREFOX_VERSION=45.8.0
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=4
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=4
```

Even though I override NODE_MAX_INSTANCES and NODE_MAX_SESSION I still see 
`maxSession=1` and `maxInstances=1` in `/opt/selenium/config.json`, so the question is that what could be the issue here as mostly it is the same config as in official selenium docker wiki ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I found the answer [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/357)

Copy from maintainer's comment:

> that functionality was released first in 2.53.1-americium. when
>   releasing americium, we didn't have the fleshed out release process,
>   so the image version you have "2.53.1" doesn't have that functionality
>   to add "NODE_MAX_INSTANCES" and such. You can get this functionality
>   by using the version 2.53.1-americium or 2.53.1-beryllium whichever
>   you wish.